# How do I sum constant numbers to innerWidth in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, string-concatenation

I'm trying to sum the `innerWidth` and `constant numbers` in JS, but the browser keeps just attaching those numbers, not calculating.

[image]

The weird thing is giving minus values are working fine. The browser doesn't calculate only when I try to sum the numbers to `innerWidth`.

Are there any ways to solve this issue?

```
  Slider.prototype.sizeReseting = function(event) {
    this.frame.style.height = (window.innerWidth - '300') + 'px';
    this.frame.style.width = (window.innerWidth - '300') + 'px';
    this.film.style.height = (window.innerWidth - '400') + 'px';
    this.film.style.width = (window.innerWidth + '100') + 'px';
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are [concatenating strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators).

In JavaScript, strings are defined between quotes or double quotes. Hence `var thing = 100;` is a number but `var thing = '100';` is a string.

Strings are just a bunch of characters, with *no numeral value* (Not actually true, but for you to understand this easily). Having a string `var thing = '100';` has the same number value as having the string `var thing = 'asd';`, which is none.

Concatenating two strings gives the concatenation as a result, hence `"asd" + "zxc"` result in `"asdzxc"`, the same way you concatenate two strings like this: `"100" + "100"` results in `"100100"`.

For your code to work, just remove the string delimitation and sum actual numbers, like this:

```
this.film.style.width = (window.innerWidth + 100) + 'px';
```

Note how I removed the single quotes around `100` for it to be an actual number.

Comment: To put it easily, OP is concatenating string...?

Comment: Thank you for answering. It helps me.

Comment: Hi @l3lue, if it helps please considering to it be an "accepted" answer for the ease of understanding for the community, thanks

Comment: Yes @YashKaranke, because of the quotes. If you sum a number to a string, because there's a string it is actually concatenating it. What actually happens in the background is that a type conversion with `toString()` is made to the number and then concatenated to the other string.

Answer (score 2):

#### Explanation:

This 2 lines have very different results:

```
this.film.style.height = (window.innerWidth - '400') + 'px';
this.film.style.width = (window.innerWidth + '100') + 'px';
```

- In the first one, the sign `-` converts your sting `400` to a number. Therefore,  you're **substracting** 400 to the value of window.innerWidth (and then adding the string 'px')
- In the second one, the sign `+` is acting as a [concatenation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators). Therefore, you're **concatenating** the result of  `window.innerWidth` + the string `'100'` + the string `'px'`.

#### Solution:

Just remove the single quotes from your code:

```
this.film.style.width = (window.innerWidth + 100) + 'px';
```